# How to remove Hour, Minute, and Second from Epoch timestamp

Tags: java, date, epoch, milliseconds

I need to write a function that accepts a `java.util.Date` and removes the hours, minutes, and milliseconds from it **USING JUST MATH (no Date formatters, no Calendar objects, etc.)**:

```
private Date getJustDateFrom(Date d) {
    //remove hours, minutes, and seconds, then return the date
}
```

The purpose of this method is to get the date from a millisecond value, without the time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private Date getJustDateFrom(Date d) {
    long milliseconds = d.getTime();
    return new Date(milliseconds - (milliseconds%(1000*60*60)));
}
```

The problem is, this only removes minutes and seconds. I don't know how to remove hours.

If I do `milliseconds - (milliseconds%(1000*60*60*23))`, then it goes back to 23:00 hrs on the previous day.

**EDIT:**

Here's an alternative solution:

```
public static Date getJustDateFrom(Date d) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Will this solution be affected by time zone differences between the client/server sides of my app?

Comment: What's the purpose of this method? If you only want the day, month, year, use the `Calendar`'s get.

Comment: does it always go to 23:00 on the previous day? If that's the case, can't you just add 1 hour?

Comment: I read that `Calendar` object takes the timezone into consideration. I have a web app that gets this Date object from a client, and I don't want it to be affected by timezones.

Comment: @Cruncher that seems a bit hacky. I don't want this to be affected by leap years or DST.

Comment: @churro You're trying to derive a date from milliseconds. Leap years are going to have to be accounted for

Comment: @Cruncher, good point. The problem I'm trying to solve is getting the Date out of a millisecond value, without the time. Can you suggest a more appropriate way to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest something super-simple... Get the `new Date()` object.  Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to output it to a `String`.  Use the same SDF object to parse that string.  Then get the millis from the `Date` object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are 24 hours in a day. Use milliseconds%(1000*60*60*24).

Comment: Doesn't work:
in:  `Tue Oct 01 11:15:08 PDT 2013` 
out: `Mon Sep 30 17:00:00 PDT 2013`

Comment: Well, like you said, you are trying to avoid daylight savings adjustments. I believe you will find that 17:00:00 PDT is midnight GMT. This IS the answer to the question you asked... Perhaps you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: You are right, I may be asking the wrong question. The base issue is that I want the Date milliseconds without the time. Maybe I should take a different approach?

Comment: Yes. Use Calendar. Specifically, GregorianCalendar will have a lot of the functions you will want for dealing with time zones, leap years, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using `Calendar` now.

Answer (score 2):

Simply not possible by your definition.

A millisecond timestamp represents milliseconds elapsed from a fixed point in time (1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC, if I remember correctly). This timestamp can not be converted into a date + time without specifying the timezone to convert to.

So you can only round the timestamp to full days in respect to a specific timezone, not in general. So any fiddling with Date.getTime() and not taking into account any timezone is *guaranteed* to work in only one time zone - the one you hardcoded for.

Do yourself a favor and use a Calendar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems I did not understand `Date`s too well, and will have to use a `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of apache's commons lang DateUtils helper utility class.

For example, if you had the datetime of 28 Mar 2002
     13:45:01.231, if you passed with Calendar.HOUR, it would return 28 Mar
       2002 13:00:00.000.  If this was passed with Calendar.MONTH, it would
      return 1 Mar 2002 0:00:00.000.

```
Date newDate = DateUtils.truncate(new Date(1408338000000L), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

You can download commons lang jar at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Date;


long dateInEpoch = 1_592_283_050_000L;

ZoneId defaultZoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
long currentDate = Date
        .from(new Date(dateInEpoch)
                .toLocalDate()
                .atStartOfDay(defaultZoneId)
                .toInstant())
        .getTime();
```

input : 1592283050000
output: 1592245800000

Comment: Thanks for showing a modern solution. When using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as you do here, I prefer not to involve the two old `Date` classes (`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`, both poorly designed and both outdated).

Comment: How about `Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateInEpoch).atZone(defaultZoneId).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant().toEpochMilli()`?